# How to put a validation in form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i know this may be simple, but i am new to js and i am still learning. so i have this on my main.handlebars

```
<form method="post" action="/save" onsubmit="return validateform()" name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="{{username}}">
</form>
```

on the other page which is main.js i have my function

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

but it is not working and i dont know how to fix it please help me thank you

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. Your call is in all lowercase (`validateform()`), but your function's name has an uppercase `F` (`validateForm`). They have to match.

Comment: Separately, I'd recommend you don't use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, because amongst other things they can only call global functions, and in general it's best to avoid creating global functions. Instead, use modern event handling ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and such).

Comment: Since this is effectively a "typo"-style question, I suggest deleting it with the "delete" button under the question text. Happy coding!

Comment: it is still working, its like it cannot call the function validateForm(), how can i connect the two files main.handlebars and main.js?

Answer (score -1):

You have typing mistake in you function call "validateform()" and function defination "validateForm"

> " f " and capital " F " in them

as javaScript is case sensitive language

else looks fine in first, can you make sure that you have a Submit in there,
and you proper action on "/save".
if you can add your action and submit code, it will be help to understand if some error in that part.

Here's [Code](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_js)
I think you followed and you understand "The action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted".
To no more about action [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

Comment: is still working, its like it cannot call the function validateForm(), how can i connect the two files main.handlebars and main.js?

Comment: you are degrading my answer but it is a mistake in your current code what I can see. but it is Ok if it didn't work for you. if you want to connect a javaScript file in html you have to user this in your head then you can use all variables and function in your html page.

`<script src="main.js"></script>` 

for more [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp)

Let me know if this helpful for you :)

Comment: I am grateful that it helps you, please up vote my answer if I solved your problem,
happy coding :)